# How do I center <h2> and <img> elements that are inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align h2 and img (icon) elements and I know that I should add display: inline-block but they shifted to the left of the section. How can I center them?

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Coffee</h2>
<img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/coffee.jpg" alt="coffee icon"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -8px;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhpI.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use a `<div>` to center everything inside (text and image) using `text-align`:

```
<style>
div
{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div>
  <h2>Coffee</h2>
  <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/coffee.jpg" alt="coffee icon"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap both h2 and img tags in parent div so you can apply flexbox property easily and center both element.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
div img{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Coffee</h2>
<img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/coffee.jpg" alt="coffee icon"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To center the text "Coffee" and the cup image inside a section as shown in the screenshot, you can add `text-align: center` to the `<section>` element in CSS. This will align all elements inside the section to the center.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Making `<h2>` as *inline-block*, the width become the length of the text "Coffee". Therefore, `text-align: center` doesn't work.